# How to take the time coordinate in a NetCDF file to use a title string in Python

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am using NetCDF4 dataset to plot some data.

[image: dataset information]

I want to take the time coordinate to use as a string for the title of a plot.
A basic question, but how do I do this?

I got as far as to this, but how do I select the '2023-12-05T12:00:00.000000000' only?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I knew it was going to be something really simple. I will answer my own question.

To extract the value you can use the attribute ".data"

ie
myds['time'].data

[image]